# bashrc function -e file check is always false

Tags: bash, awk

Bashrc function receives a filename. The -e and/or -f check always returns false, even if i don't use a variable.

```
FILE=/var/log/nginx/$1
if [[ -e "$FILE" ]]; then
        echo "exists"
else
        echo "not"
fi
sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/$1 | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

The latter awk command works fine, but the if statement is always false.

This still returns false and the awk command still works:

```
    FILE=/var/log/nginx/dtb_access
    if [[ -e $FILE ]]; then
        echo "exists"
    else
        echo "not"
    fi
    sudo awk '{print $1}' $FILE | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

**update**

```
views() {
    set -x
    file=/var/log/nginx/$1
    if [[ -e "$file" ]]; then
        echo "exists"
    else
        echo "not"
    fi
    sudo awk '{print $1}' "$file" | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
    set +x
}
```

output of `views dtb_access`:

```
+ file=/var/log/nginx/dtb_access
+ [[ -e /var/log/nginx/dtb_access ]]
+ echo not
not
+ wc -l
+ uniq
+ sort
+ cut '-d ' -f1
+ sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/dtb_access
7
+ set +x
```

I've tried putting the variable in both types of quotations and none at all. I've tried just using a static string and no variable, every time it's the same outcome

Comment: Debug, add `set -x` after the shebang  or `bash -x ./myscript`, Also paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any carriage return characters in the script. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Is it actually running under bash, or some other shell? Do you get any error messages? Does `$1` contain anything weird like a wildcard?

Comment: @GordonDavisson It's just a function in .bashrc. $1 is just a string. if i replace the var with the actual filename it still returns false but the awk command works. No visible error

Comment: Just because it's a function in bashrc doesn't mean you can't use `set -x` to debug it. `set -x; yourfunction dtb_access; set +x`

Comment: BTW, your code is somewhat buggy in that it's not using quotes on the awk command line. If there are spaces at the end of `$FILE`, the unquoted expansion would discard them, which would explain your symptoms here. That's no longer the case if you change it to `awk '{print $1}' "$FILE"`

Comment: BTW, don't use all-caps names for your own variables -- those names are reserved for variables that reflect or modify shell behavior; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, which specifies that the namespace of variables with at least one lowercase character is reserved for applications. That's your script -- an application. (Read that specification keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a namespace, since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named, preexisting environment variable).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've appended an update

Comment: Interesting. Honestly, I'd be doing a much lower-level investigation here -- digging into the filesystem you're using, syscall-level tracing of script execution, any security layers that could be getting involved, etc. `test` generally uses `stat()` or `access()`, which are separate syscalls from `open()`, but for a standard filesystem with nothing weird going on, inconsistent behavior between them is a very surprising bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've switched to root user and it works. How can i run the -e check as sudo?

Comment: Apparently, the test is failing silently when I'd expect it to report a permission error. It's also a silent error with bash's builtin `[ ]` and `test` commands, as well as the external `[` and `test` binaries on the OSes I've tried. Very strange.

Comment: Aside: `awk '{print $1}' $FILE | cut -d" " -f1` makes no sense since `awk` is outputting the first space-separated field so what `cut` sees cannot have a blank in it so `cut -d" " -f1` is doing nothing. Also `sort | uniq` = `sort -u`. So instead of `awk '{print $1}' "$file" | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l` you could have written `awk '{print $1}' "$file" | sort -u | wc -l` which could be written as just a single command instead of a pipeline of multiple commands: `awk '!seen[$1]++{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' "$file"`

Comment: _facepalm_; I completely missed the `sudo` earlier. As others have said, you can use `sudo` to call an _out-of-process_ test like `test` or `[`, even though it can't be used for an in-process one like `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
file="/var/log/nginx/dtb_access"
if sudo test -e "$file"; then
  echo "exists"
else
  echo "not"
fi

sudo awk ...
```

as the user running the script may not have access to `/var/log/nginx` and therefore `-e` fails.